# Reset state of service in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I'm a bit confused when it comes to the state of an AngularJs service. I have a section in my webpage where the user goes through multiple steps (that is, multiple views) to create the resource X. The steps contain settings for resource X and these settings need to follow the user until the last step where the resource X is created in the database as a request to the backend. The user should be able to go back and edit data in this process, meaning that just using the same controller does not work since it is reloaded on page view.

I therefore wrote a service to keep the state between views. The problem is that the state of the service must be reset somehow. For example, if the user logs out and another user logs in, it has the state of the previous user. Or when the resource X has been created against the backend, the state should be reset so that the user can create another resource X with new settings/values.

What is the best way to do this in angular?

EDIT: Should I just have a method reset() in the service, or how do people do this?

Comment: So on your log in, log out mechanism, call a method on your service which wipes the state?

Comment: Sure, i could have a method reset() in the service. However, is this the way people do it?

Comment: When the user logs out you should properly clear all things related to the old user. Usually this is done via an `Auth` service that manages user sessions.

Comment: The way someone would do it, is, what ever made sense in the architecture and would have least amount of impact on the design. Which by the sounds of it a `reset` method would have. Alternatively you could have a event watcher so you could keep the service fully self contained.